# Make SQL return one row for every WHERE clause, even if identical to previous one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with two columns that stores translations from English to German (labelled "english" and "german").  I lookup translations with a query like:

```
SELECT german 
FROM translate_content 
WHERE german = "A" || german = "B" || german = "C" || german = "A";
```

My problem is that sometimes the same word will appear on a page multiple times (in this case the word "A"), and I need the number of rows in my SQL result to match the number of words I want to translate.  SQL will return rows like this:

```
A
B
C
```

but I need it to return

```
A
B
C
A
```

How can I accomplish this?  If it helps I am using MySQL.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and bad design. Really - even if some word can appear multiple times in page - why do you need it to appear multiple times (and having duplicates) in query output?

Comment: Please show the data in the able for your example

Comment: I am curious to know why you would ever do this.  You cannot determine which rows map to which clause, it would make more sense to have 4 different queries.

Comment: @ergonaut - because I could solve my problem in one line of code, rather than rewriting an entire class that I want nothing to do with ;)  I'm all for best practice, but sometimes I can't justify the time it would take when the existing solution works.

Comment: The HTML that will be shown on this page contains many placeholder strings of the format \_\_content\_\_.  I use preg_match_all to find all instances of the placeholders, and then search for the matched values in the database.  If I can make the number of SQL results match the number of placeholders then I can just use str_replace using the arrays as parameters, rather than looking them up one at a time as the content is assembled, or using extra code to match the translations to the placeholders where multiples are found.

Comment: @user3640967 then hopefully you will not run into an issue if union does not return the results in the order you want as it does not guarantee this.  Otherwise it's best to return a dictionary (eg. select english, german ...) to do a mapping.

Comment: Could you think of an example where it would not return in the right order?  Ie the order the clauses were presented in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT german 
FROM translate_content 
WHERE german = "A"
UNION ALL
SELECT german 
FROM translate_content 
WHERE german = "B"
UNION ALL
SELECT german 
FROM translate_content 
WHERE german = "C"
UNION ALL
SELECT german 
FROM translate_content 
WHERE german = "A"
```

Comment: I would suggest that if you can handle this in your business logic, would be great, to check if the key is duplicate, so that you can optimize your query to something like `SELECT german 
FROM translate_content 
WHERE german = "A" OR german = "B" OR german = "C" UNION ALL SELECT german 
FROM translate_content 
WHERE german = "A"`

Comment: Thanks - I'm not sure if that will be possible with the current setup, but it will definitely need optimising at some point so I'll save this for later!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a `join` for this:

```
SELECT tc.german 
FROM translate_content tc JOIN
     (SELECT 'A' as g UNION ALL SELECT 'B' UNION ALL SELECT 'C' UNION ALL SELECT 'A'
     ) v
     ON v.german = tc.german;
```

Give the structure of your question, you don't even need the `translate_content` table.  The following returns what you are asking for:

```
SELECT 'A' as g UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C' UNION ALL
SELECT 'A';
```

However, I suspect different column names might be involved.
         )

Answer (score 0):

Look into using DISTINCT, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html.

Here is a good explanation about DISTINCT and GROUP BY: [GROUP BY does not remove duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152333/group-by-does-not-remove-duplicates)

Comment: Distinct is the opposite of what I want, no?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query maybe useful for you.

```
SELECT german 
FROM translate_content 
WHERE german LIKE "A" OR german LIKE "B" OR german LIKE "C" OR german LIKE "A";
```

Comment: I don't have the reputation to vote this down but you've clearly not read the question.

Comment: @user3640967 then first explain your question clearly. You dont have rights to blame any helper who try to help you out.

Comment: @user3640967 Ok sometime some are getting what you trying to say but someone not get that doesn't mean that you talk like that specially for that person who trying to solve your bug.

Comment: Yes, right if you don't like answer then don't implement. i am not forcing you to implement it.

Comment: It's not a case of not liking it - it doesn't do what the question asked.